# Kernel xconfig for cross-compilation fails with "no package 'qt-mt' found error"

Tags: kernel, compiling, qt

I am cross-compiling a Kernel.org Linux kernel (linux-3.0.4) for an embedded ARM system.  A few days ago, I was able to successfully build the kernel xconfig on an Ubuntu 11.04 Natty (64-bit) host desktop using gcc and a cross-compiler.  I've also tried the same compilation process on an Ubuntu 11.10 (64-bit) desktop.  However, I now receive the following errors related to package 'qt-mt':

```
$ make ARCH=arm xconfig
Package qt-mt was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `qt-mt.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'qt-mt' found
Package qt-mt was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `qt-mt.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'qt-mt' found
Package qt-mt was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `qt-mt.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'qt-mt' found
Package qt-mt was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `qt-mt.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'qt-mt' found
HOSTCXX scripts/kconfig/qconf.o
scripts/kconfig/qconf.cc:6:21: fatal error: qglobal.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/qconf.o] Error 1
make: *** [xconfig] Error 2
```

The xconfig is being run on the host Ubuntu desktop to prepare the kernel options for a cross-compiled kernel image.  Since the xconfig is run on the host, it is not being built with the cross-compiler.  I have no clue what is happening here, but I think it might be related to where the qt libraries are installed on Ubuntu.

I've found the following thread on the Fedora forum, but I don't know if it applies to my situation on Ubuntu.

http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=139653

I've also tried to uninstall and reinstall QT3 and QT4 using the apt tools, but the error given above still persists.  Any suggestions on what I could do to successfully compile xconfig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was answered by the OP

> With more experimentation, a
>
> ```
> make distclean
> ```
>
> seemed to fix the problem. I can now build the kernel xconfig successfully.